# Appcelerator Splash Screen not showing up

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, splash-screen

I replaced all the `default.png` with my default.png that i want to show when my app starts, to `app/assets/android/images` but a white screen appeared.

I tried also to put these images as `background.9.png` to the folders `platform/android/res` but it didn't work again.

Did i forgot something? Any suggessions?

Comment: try uploading your splash screen at ticons, it will give you all the assets you need at the correct path. Try adding the new images to your project and try again: http://ticons.fokkezb.nl

Comment: Put your default.png in Resources/android and try clean and run again. also  refer http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens

Comment: Unfortunatelly none of these worked for me. When i clean & build the project i see the custom default.png in Resources/android , but still not showing up

Comment: If you generate a new Titanium project, then  modify/replace the default splash screens at the exact same place they were at you still get a white screen as splash? Are you sure that white screen is not your app and that the plash screen appears before that or maybe not even (if you computer is really fast)?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. After replacing the screens and tried the default screen and also 9 patch screens, it shows white screen as the splash. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using http://ticons.fokkezb.nl for splash screen generation, it gives you the correct images in the correct path.

I'm using it for every app and it works!